# How to add custom font into pdf-lib

Tags: pdf-lib.js

I am attempting to add a custom font to the pdf-lib library, but I am encountering an error: 'Unknown font format.' I have tried TTF, OTF, WOFF, and WOFF2 fromats, but none of them seem to work. Could someone please help me identify what I might be doing wrong in this process?

```
  const url = "./Roboto-Italic.ttf";
  const fontBytes = await fetch(url).then((res) => res.arrayBuffer());
  pdfDoc.registerFontkit(fontkit);
  const font = await pdfDoc.embedFont(fontBytes);
```

error:

```
    at Object.create (http://localhost:3000/main.86466a5e8eefe1529961.hot-update.js:8806:11)
    at Function.<anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/main.86466a5e8eefe1529961.hot-update.js:47584:42)
    at step (http://localhost:3000/main.86466a5e8eefe1529961.hot-update.js:56459:17)
    at Object.next (http://localhost:3000/main.86466a5e8eefe1529961.hot-update.js:56408:14)
    at http://localhost:3000/main.86466a5e8eefe1529961.hot-update.js:56382:67
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at __awaiter (http://localhost:3000/main.86466a5e8eefe1529961.hot-update.js:56364:10)
    at CustomFontEmbedder.for (http://localhost:3000/main.86466a5e8eefe1529961.hot-update.js:47579:60)
    at PDFDocument.<anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/main.86466a5e8eefe1529961.hot-update.js:35659:91)
    at step (http://localhost:3000/main.86466a5e8eefe1529961.hot-update.js:56459:17)
```

Answer (score 1):

Most PDF libraries will use a TTF font for PDF mapping "ToUnicode". but there are security restrictions on imbedding binary fonts from external sources into a text based carrier like a PDF wrapper.

PDF-LIB uses a fontkit which needs to do the necessary embedding of pulling a remote untainted binary.ttf into a clients text based HTML editor. So follow the guides for adding more than the font-less 14 Standard Fonts embedded in PDF Viewers / Reader-editors.

[image]
[image]

Beware as shown above some fonts may not work well without some fettling so for example this Ballet font thinks its  `Ball   et`

```
<html><head><meta charset="utf-8" />
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/pdf-lib@1.4.0"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/@pdf-lib/fontkit@0.0.4"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/downloadjs@1.4.7"></script>
    <style>
      body {width: 100vw;height: 100vh;display: flex;justify-content: center;lign-items: center;flex-direction: column;}
      p {font-family: helvetica;font-size: 24px;text-align: center;margin: 25px;}
      .small {font-family: helvetica;font-size: 18px;text-align: center;margin: 25px;}
      button {background-color: #008CBA;border: none;color: white;padding: 15px 32px;text-align: center;font-size: 16px;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
      <p>Click the button to embed a custom font and measure text drawn in that font with <code>pdf-lib</code></p>
      <button onclick="embedFontAndMeasureText()">Create PDF</button>
      <p class="small">(Your browser will download the resulting file)</p>
</body>

  <script>
    const { PDFDocument, rgb } = PDFLib

    async function embedFontAndMeasureText() {
      const url = 'https://fonts.cdnfonts.com/s/107471/Ballet[opsz].ttf' // Fetch custom font from FULL UNTAINTED URL
      const fontBytes = await fetch(url).then(res => res.arrayBuffer())
      const pdfDoc = await PDFDocument.create() // Create a new PDFDocument
      pdfDoc.registerFontkit(fontkit)  // Register the `fontkit` instance
      const Font15 = await pdfDoc.embedFont(fontBytes)  // Embed custom font in the doc in addition to 14 standard ones

      const page = pdfDoc.addPage()  // Add a blank page to the document

      const text = 'This  is  text  in  remote  embedded  Ballet  font!'  // Create a string of plain text 
      const textSize = 30
      const textWidth = Font15.widthOfTextAtSize(text, textSize) // measure text at size at its custom width and height
      const textHeight = Font15.heightAtSize(textSize)

      // Draw the string of text using Font_15 on the page
      page.drawText(text, {
        x: 40,
        y: 450,
        size: textSize,
        font: Font15,
        color: rgb(0.25, 0.50, 0.75),
      })

      // Draw a box around the string of text
      page.drawRectangle({
        x: 40,
        y: 450,
        width: textWidth,
        height: textHeight,
        borderColor: rgb(1, 0, 0),
        borderWidth: 1.5,
      })

      // Serialize the PDFDocument to bytes (a Uint8Array)
      const pdfBytes = await pdfDoc.save()

            // Trigger the browser to download the PDF document
      download(pdfBytes, "pdf-lib_creation_example.pdf", "application/pdf");
    }
  </script>
</html>
```